# Format a calculation value as currency

Tags: jquery, numeral.js

I have the following calculation that I would like to format as a currency:

```
jQuery(function () {

  $("#weight").change(function () {
    var iva = $("#iva").val();
    var subtotal = $("#subtotal").val();
    var total = parseFloat(iva) + parseFloat(subtotal);

    $("#total").val(total.toFixed(2));
  })
})
```

I have tried the numeral.js plug in change the last line to:

```
$("#total").val(total.format('$0,0.00'));
```

but this is not working (no calculation at all.

What is the proper way to use the plugin in this instance?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call the `numeral()` function on `total` to use the plugin's `format()` function:

```
$("#total").val(numeral(total).format('$0,0.00'));
```

This creates a `Numeral` object with a value of `total`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!